# Error With Keyboard Input in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I have been working on this and I cannot figure out why it won't move properly.  It only moves left when I press the D code.  Please help me

```
bif = "bif.jpg"
mif = "games.png"
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
cursor=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()
x,y=4,4
movex,movey=0,0

while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==K_a:
            movex=-3
        elif event.key==K_d:
            movex=+3
        elif event.key==K_s:
            movey=+3
        elif event.key==K_w:
            movey= -3
    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key==K_a:
                    movex=0
        elif event.key==K_w:
            movex=0
        elif event.key==K_s:
            movey=0
        elif event.key==K_d:
            movey= 0

            x = x + movex
            y = y+movex

screen.blit(background, (0,0))

screen.blit(cursor, (x,y))
pygame.display.update()
```

is it possible that it is a hardware error?

Comment: `y = y+movex` should be `y += movey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the indentation for

> ```
>         x = x + movex
>         y = y+movex
> ```

It will only be run when KEYUP and K_d. Try unindenting it to have it run after each keypress. It should be at the same level as the `if` statements.